# fine-uploader - setname | getname via Api

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I'm using the fine-uploader version 4.0.3 and i try to use the methods setName and getName to edit the original filname after submit a file.

`.on('submit', function (event, id, name) {
    $("#fine-uploader").fineUploader({setName: {id: "test"}})
})`

But this does not working!

Can you give me a code example how i can use the setName method via api?

Thanks!

Michael

Comment: This is covered in the documentation.  See http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/jquery.html

Comment: Hi Ray,

thank's for your quick answer! :-)

I change the code and now the uploaded file get's the new name. But how can i update the name in the upload list. At the moment the upload list shows the original filename and only the uploaded file get's the new name. How can I update the filename in the upload list?


  $("#fine-uploader").fineUploader('setName', 0, 'test')

Comment: Why don't you just use the built-in support that allows users to edit file names in Fine Uploader UI?  What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Hi, i create an upload for a email-campaign-system. Every file needs to get a additional labeling (categories) of the files. Before the submitted-event the user should select via popup the category and this category should be added to the filename.

Comment: Looks like this is not a workflow I tested/covered.  Can you please open up an issue in the Github repo?  I'll document a workaround in my answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the name of a file via the `setName` [API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/methods.html), the UI will not be automatically updated in Fine Uploader UI.  The only way this will currently happen is if you edit the file name directly via the UI using [Fine Uploader UI's edit filename feature](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/filename-edit.html).

A workaround, until this workflow is covered, would be to update the UI yourself.  The simplest way to do this would be to select the element in the file list in your submitted event handler, and change the text of the file name element accordingly.  So, if you are using jQuery (which you are), your workaround would look something like this:

```
$("#fineUploader").fineUploader().on("submitted", function(event, id, name) {
    var $fileItem = $(this).fineUploader("getItemByFileId", id),
        newName = $(this).fineUploader("getName", id);

    $fileItem.find(".qq-upload-file-selector").text(newName);
});
```

Note that this must occur in your submitted callback (or later) since the file item isn't added to the UI until the submitted callback is invoked.  You'll note that the name parameter passed to the submitted callback is also stale.  This is another issue that should be fixed when work to support this workflow is completed.